# How to output raw frequency (fft) data using ffmpeg / libavfilter

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec

I'm trying to write libavfilter bindings to convert an arbitrary audio file into a raw frequency (spectrum) data to do subsequent audio analysis. Is there anything built-in ffmpeg or libavfilter to output binary frequency data, rather than a proper audio/video file?

FFmpeg has a few built-in filters that perform an FFT such as [afftfilt](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/af_afftfilt.c) and [showfreqs](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/avf_showfreqs.c), however these filters always convert output back to video or audio. What I need is something like the `afftfilt` filter, but which dumps the raw FFT data, rather than recode it back to PCM.

Comment: When you say _binary frequency data_, what format is that going to take? Would it be a sequence of float pairs for real and imaginary parts? or would it be frequency bin and magnitude pairs?

Comment: Any format works for me, I guess re+im pairs as returned by fft would make sense.

Comment: Is there a reason for the limitation to FFmpeg / libav? For instance, would there be a problem in using [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org) where [complex output is just an array of 2 doubles](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-numbers.html#Complex-numbers)?

Comment: Just putting in a note that you may want Constant Q data instead of FT data, but the output would still be an array/stream of complex numbers.

Comment: if this was any success, answering could help me

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how accurate you need the FFT to be, and whether you need the imaginary part, you could macgyver something out of the `showspectrum` filter output - have it output to raw bitmaps and treat these as byte arrays.